# Trying to pass a variable from JQuery to PHP

Tags: php, jquery

So, I've looked at several questions and answers here, and they all seem to point in the same direction, but I just can't make it work. . .

I want to read a variable from a file in JQuery, add one to it, then pass it to php to write the new value to the file. I have separate HTML/JavaScript and PHP files.

In the Javascript, I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data
    $.get('scoredir/data.txt', function(data) {
        count = parseInt(data);
        count = count +1;
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'savedata.php',
        data: { 'numberOfPlays' : count },   
        success: function (response) {
            //alert (response);
        }
    }); 
});
```

In the php file (savedata.php), I have:

```
<?php 
    $data = $_POST['numberOfPlays'];
    file_put_contents("scoredir/data.txt", $data);
?>
```

It seems like the php file just isn't getting the variable. Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: where is count declared??

Comment: Hi. Put the ajax call. After the count+1. And inner the funtion of the 'get'.

Comment: @user3670826 `localhost` environment ?

Answer (score 0):

You're having typical asynchronous AJAX issues. You're `$.ajax` command is running before your `$.get` command has completed it's request.

For a quick-fix, try something like this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data;

    $.get('scoredir/data.txt', function(data) {
        count = parseInt(data);
        count = count +1;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'savedata.php',
            data: { 'numberOfPlays' : count },   
            success: function (response) {
                //alert (response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Also, look into [deferred objects and promises](http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/).

Answer (score 0):

I think behavior of ajax is async so one is getting completed and other is not or may be vice-versa, so you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('scoredir/data.txt', function(data) {
        var count = parseInt(data); // you can declare your variable here
            count = count + 1;

        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'savedata.php',
           data: { 'numberOfPlays' : count },   
           success: function (response) {
               //alert (response);
           }
        }); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is, $.get is just a shorthand, it is already an asynchronous ajax call. Therefore, in order to work with the result (e.g. count) of that request, your second ajax call needs to go inside the callback of $.get like so:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
        var count;
        $.get('http://echo.jsontest.com/key/22', function(data) {
            count = parseInt(data.key);
            count = count +1;

            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'savedata.php',
              data: { 'numberOfPlays' : count },   
              success: function (response) {
                  //alert (response);
              }
            }); 

        });

    });
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/3Pykx/